# RandomAccessFile.read() returns value greater than number of characters read into string

Tags: java, java-io, file-read

I have a `RandomAccessFile raFile` from which I'm reading data into a buffer in fixed sized chunks:

```java
byte[] fileBuffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

while((readBytes = raFile.read(fileBuffer) >= 0) {
    String bufferStr = new String(fileBuffer, 0, readBytes);
    String testerStr = new String(fileBuffer);

    System.out.println(readBytes+","+bufferStr.length()+","+testerStr.length());
}
```

What I had expected was for `raFile.read()` to read as many bytes as the `BUFFER_SIZE` (except at the end of the file) and the same value to be copied to `readBytes`. While this is mostly true, occasionally, I get the following outputs for a `BUFFER_SIZE` of 4096:

`readBytes` `bufferStr` `testerStr`
 4096             4092              4092 
 4096             4090              4090 
 4096             4094              4094 
 4096             4095              4095

If 4096 bytes are being read, why is the length of `bufferStr` and `testerStr` less than this value even when not at file end?

Reference: [This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#read%28byte%5b%5d%29) says `read()` returns the total number of bytes read into the buffer.

Comment: Do you have multibyte characters in your file? string length is in chars and readBytes length is in bytes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there are characters that need more than one byte. bufferStr.lenght() gives you the number of characters, not the number of bytes.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between the bytes read and the count of characters in the String created out of these bytes. A byte read out of the stream allways has 8 bit. A character of a string can have up to 16 bit (Unicode). So two bytes of the input can result in one character in the String created.

Answer (score 0):

True point by Pablo.
try:

```
    System.out.println(readBytes+","+bufferStr.getBytes().length+
          +","+testerStr.getBytes().length);
```

and see the result.